# Creating new variable names, Symbol or ToExpression

Tags: string-manipulation, variable-definitions, symbols, variable

One can create new variable names by Symbol :

```
In[1]  Table[Symbol["x"<>ToString[i]], {i,1,5}]
Out[1]  {x1,x2,x3,x4,x5}
```

But it is also possible to use ToExpression (old friend) :

```
In[2]  Table[ToExpression["x"<>ToString[i]], {i,1,5}]
Out[2]  {x1,x2,x3,x4,x5}
```

There is a difference : Symbol will produce an error for incorrect variable names while ToExpression will do something meaningful.

```
In[3]  Table[Symbol[ToString[i]<>"x"], {i,1,5}]
Out[3]  (* some error message with non-helpful output)

In[4]  Table[ToExpression[ToString[i]<>"x"], {i,1,5}]
Out[4]  {x,2x,3x,4x,5x}
```

Other than this, I see there is no difference. Is there a situation such that Symbol is more useful than ToExpression ?

Comment: well if you want to make sure you have a variable name at the end, `Symbol` lets you `Check` for the error and do something different instead!

Comment: `ToExpression["foo", StandardForm, Hold]` can be useful.

Comment: Thank you both answeres! 
@Michael E2 : The code always generates Hold[foo] when even foo has a value.

Comment: One big difference is that ToExpression can be dangerous, e.g. `ToExpression["Quit[]"]`. If you don't know where the string came from, it is risky to use ToExpression. Even if you use the 3-arg form with Hold, a clever person could construct a dangerous string that will do things that you will not expect.